# Is there an English verb for making something dynamic that works in a web development context?

Tags: wording

Not sure if this is more appropriate for Stack Overflow, but I'm a web nerd constantly using the invented word *dynamic-ify* to describe taking a flat, static web page and converting it into something that can be edited dynamically with a content management system.

Is there a real verb that'd be more appropriate in web development discussions?

Comment: There's [dynamize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dynamize) ... (sense 2: *to make dynamic :  endow with force*)

Comment: @Hellion *endow with force* fits nicely! Would you mind making that an answer, or is my first post an offensive failed-to-use-dictionary type that should be deleted?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it "offensive".  :-)  But yes, it does seem likely to be closed for "not enough research" or the like.

Comment: @Matt: No - *dynamize* isn't at all appropriate for your context. As Hellion says, it means *to endow with energy/force/dynamism*, whereas what you want is a word meaning ***make interactive/context-sensitive***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see your point, but it seems to be walking a fine line. *Animate* (suggested as an answer) could be applied but would be confused in the context of web design/development, whereas *dynamize* still seems appropriate as it's taking a static thing and endowing it with dynamism.

Comment: @Matt: No - *animate* doesn't work for your context either. You can have a non-interactive non-context-sensitive web page that happens to include animated graphics, for example. I'm not convinced there *is* an English verb for the action you're trying to describe. If I were you I'd just stick with standard compound expressions such as *"I want to make [these web pages] dynamic"*, or *make them interactive*, or *make them context-sensitive*, etc.

Comment: The term "dynamic" has become so overused, especially in the programming world, that it basically doesn't mean anything anymore. I would really try to get away from it, if at all possible. You might consider being more specific: what exactly is the change you're going for? An example might be "ajaxify", if you're adding ajax to make the site more responsive.

Comment: @KevinWorkman, you make a really good point. You've got me thinking the word I want is *templatize*, which is apparently made up as well according to the dictionary. I'm specifically referring to taking flat .html and turning it into a Twig template in this case—HTML plus a bunch of special tags that are rendered by a content management system.

Comment: @Kevin: I'd hardly say that. In programming/UI contexts, *dynamic* almost always has the specific sense of being *created at time of use, often incorporating specific pre-existing contextual information and/or capable of interactively responding to **changed** context (such as user input)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And I've heard too many clients say "make it more dynamic" yet mean completely different things to trust the word "dynamic" anymore.

Comment: @Kevin: That's probably not a "programming-specific" usage. The clients probably just mean *"Make it more **interesting** (including eye-catching moving graphics, etc.)"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm in the weird area of (mostly front-end) web *design* and *development*, where unfortunately the meaning could be related to programming or design depending on who I'm talking with. And even then, it could come down to which goal we're addressing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly. I'm not sure how what you're saying is disagreeing with me.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for your input @FumbleFingers!

Comment: @Matt: I think the range of suggestions given in answers and comments here (all inappropriate, imho) shows there's no obvious "ordinary English" word for your context. But the activity must be really common in the UI design context, so I'd have thought the guys over at SE User Experience would have a domain-specific term for it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wonder if a mod can whisk the post off to SE UX, or if I should just re-post. I think you're right, either UX or Stack Overflow might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Matt: No - don't repost. I think you can "flag" your own question to ask for moderator attention, which allows you to say something like "Please migrate to UX". That doesn't necessarily mean they *will* do this - they might think the question should stay here. But they probably will. If you can't access the "flag" facility ping me with another comment and I'll do it for you (but I'm sure it's best if the OP makes the request). I'd say definitely UX, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a UX question. You are simply asking for a phrase for your personal use. I don't see how this would benefit future visitors. If you want to use your "invented" word, go ahead. The word you are looking for is dynamic. It's more of how you word it relating to grammar than it is trying to find a better word. It's either static or dynamic.

Comment: @CodeMaverick I agree that it's not a UX question, which is why I originally posted it to the English Language Stack Exchange. It was recommended to be moved here since it's domain-specific, but I'm starting to get the feeling there just isn't a single English verb that's perfect in this context. It's for my use, but in a fairly common situation as I point out in the question. No argument about this being off-topic here!

Comment: @MattStein - Yea, we usually migrate these sorts of questions TO English.SE, so it's odd they migrated it here. That said, I think you simply need to just say something to the effect of, _"I'm going **convert** this content from static to dynamic"_. That's really all you are doing. It's just in the wording I think, because dynamic is definitely the word you should be using.

Comment: @CodeMaverick Your suggestion seems like the only way that'd be widely understood, I was just wondering if the perfect verb exists and is being used in the wild. (There's a lot I don't know!) I think the answer is basically just "no, there isn't a word unless you make it up." If I'm asking a bad question (as opposed to a tedious one), I'm open to criticism. Seems like there's no clear answer or I've not found the right place to ask.

Comment: @MattStein - I retracted my close vote and left an [answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/72851/40110) for you that I think would really be the only way to go.

Comment: @CodeMaverick I seem to be collecting some good answers to a fairly iffy question! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dynamize is the first word that came to mind. It looks like at least one dictionary (AmE) agrees that this word fits: https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+dynamize

Comment: In terms of the actual title of the question, I think this is the correct answer. It appears "dynamize" is the single word verb form of "to make dynamic"--granted it's not a widely used word.

Comment: This isn't my favorite word, but it does precisely answer the question. Thanks @sgroves!

Answer (score 6):

Why not *[interactivate](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=interactivate)*?

> to add or enable the interactivity of something.
>
> *Boss: "Did you interactivate that screen yet?"*
>
> *Drone: "Yeah, I added the ajax calls and tablesorting last week!"*

*Urban Dictionary*

Comment: Wow, that's just as made-up but way more fun to use!

Comment: This is still growing on me because *activate* is in there, which is basically what happens to these otherwise static things. It wouldn't be potentially misunderstood like *animate* or even *activate* by itself. Too bad it's not a real word!

Comment: My thought was *activate* might be taken as taking a site from testing to live (accessible). And isn't Urban Dictionary as authoritative a source as the Oxford English Dictionary?

Comment: I've made my public appeal: http://workingconcept.com/blog/lets-interactivate

Comment: The catch is that 'interaction' and 'interactive' are typically words to describe the GUI itself--the front end.

Comment: @DA01 You're right, and in this situation I think that's actually a plus. The public site and private admin panel are both facets of the web app, whose GUI I consider to be an entirely front-end mechanism. This verb describes taking something exclusively available to the public front-end and converting it into something that can be acted upon by a *private* front end. But I still like **dynamicize** better.

Comment: @MattStein I'm not sure I understand what you are describing there. The benefit of a CMS is 'dynamic updating' not really 'interactive experience'. In otherwords, you can have a dynamic back end (CMS) but still have it producing a static experience for visitors. I think it's important to separate the front end and back end context when talking with clients.

Comment: @DA01 I guess I'm trying to say that the CMS provides the back end, but that content editors use one front end to affect another. Regardless, I agree about separating front end from back end context and your criticism that this particular answer limits its descriptive power to the front end.

Answer (score 5):

The 5th definition is for **[dynamic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dynamic)** is:

> Computers. (of data storage, processing, or programming) affected by the passage of time or the presence or absence of power: Dynamic memory must be constantly refreshed to avoid losing data.
>
> ***"Dynamic websites contain Web pages that are generated in real time."***

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a verb form, as shown below :

> [image: related forms]

Now, the only caveat to that is the word **[dynamize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dynamize)** *which is a verb* and yet doesn't appear in the above definition or related forms.

However, on it does show the following on the **[dynamize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dynamize)** definition :

> [image: dynamize origin]

---

So it seems to me that **[dynamize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dynamize)** is the way to go if you want a verb. Otherwise, my suggestion would be to simply alter how you convey your intent.

You could say any of the following:

1. I'm going to change this static content to be **[dynamic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dynamic)**.
2. I'm going to **[dynamically](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dynamically)** change this static content.
3. I'm going to **[dynamize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dynamize)** this static content.
4. Or if you are feeling creative, use the origin from the above **[dynamize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dynamize)** definition and use **dynam(ic) + -ize** to form **dynamicize**, pronounced (**dy-nam-i-cize**).

*I personally like #4 best, as creativity is always fun =D.*

Comment: Whoa...I think you and I just wrote pretty much the same answer at the same time. :)

Comment: LoL ... great minds think alike =D

Comment: Thanks both of you for slogging through this awful question!

Comment: @MattStein - No worries. It's actually interesting after I thought about it.  That's why I retracted my close vote.  I love **dynamicize (dy-nam-i-cize)**. I think that could catch on =D

Answer (score 1):

***[Animate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/animate?searchDictCode=all)*** comes to mind immediately.

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1.0 Bring to life:
>
> 1.1 Give inspiration, encouragement, or renewed vigour to:
>
> 2.0 Give (a film or character) the appearance of movement using animation techniques:
>
> *The character seemed flat and static on paper, but the actor animated the script with his unique brand of passion.*

The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=animate&allowed_in_frame=0) suggests the idea of *life*:

> 1530s, "to fill with boldness or courage,"
>
> from Latin animatus past participle of animare "give breath to," also
>   "to endow with a particular spirit, to give courage to,"
>
> from anima "life, breath" (see animus).
>
> Sense of "give life to" in English attested from 1742.

---

***[Interactivate](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=interactivate)*** has been used for the last 20 years. Many of the hits in the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interactivate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinteractivate%3B%2Cc0) are for an organization called Interactivate and its web presence, but there are specific uses of the word that approach your meaning. From [Historic Houses, Castles and Gardens](https://books.google.com/books?id=UGBOAAAAYAAJ&q=%22interactivate%22&dq=%22interactivate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Jy3JVKOxFMmhyATqp4GgDw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg):

> - Kids “**interactivate**" along the new educational play circuit through the Zoological Gardens.

From [From Energy to Information: Representation in Science and Technology, Art and Literature](https://books.google.com/books?id=_4m8fP5ZL5EC&pg=PA316&dq=%22interactivate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XCnJVO2EGYaqyQSSv4CYCg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADhk#v=onepage&q=%22interactivate%22&f=false)

> - Our ordinary impulse is to use sensors as transducers and components of control systems, and to concentrate our attention, not on the
>     spacial extension of the sensor-field, but on the task at hand.
>     Another view is possible, in which sensors ***interactivate*** space.

Comment: Interesting. In this context, to *animate* a page would refer to something different and specific, which would be about presentation (moving things around, sliding, fading, etc.) than function.

Comment: That certainly is a connotation of animate.

Comment: I've zero argument that it's a legitimate answer to my question. In practice, however, I'd confuse most people if I said I was going to "animate" a given page. My question may not be clarifying that the word/phrase should be useful in the context of web design and development.

Comment: Your answer is like the academic reference material for every idea in this post! :)

Comment: I consider my own opinion worthless unless it is informed by real life :-)

Comment: Animate is a nice word, but has rather specific meaning in the context of the web--namely front end animations. So doesn't really apply to CMSes. "Interactivate", though less so, also has that issue as 'intearctions' and 'interactive' typically refer to the GUI side of things.

Answer (score 1):

When describing how a site is built, there's usually two terms: **static** vs. **dynamic**.

Typically a static site is just HTML, CSS, and JS files that are uploaded to a server. To update the site, new static files get uploaded manually.

A dynamic site uses some form of back end technology to automate the updating and maintenance in someway--often including the addition of a Content Management System.

AFAIK, there is no particular word that would be the 'verb' form of 'dynamic'. I think for a proper term, you'd simply say "to make dynamic".

As for the other suggestions (Energize, Animate, and Interactivate) I'd say these are all words that have no bearing on the back end. These would all describe front end qualities (like interaction and animation).

@sgroves's "dynamize" is the perhaps the closest to an official way to turn 'dynamic' into a verb. Your 'dynamicify' is not a real world, but hey, it sounds catchy. Maybe go for it.

Personally, I simply say "add a Content Management System". I like to be specific.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I like being specific too, hence the quest for a verb that doesn't necessarily exist. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really a short catchy verb, but definitely more specific than *making a page dynamic* is **making it user-editable**.

Answer (score -1):

I think '[to energize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/energize) ' may fit your context: (TFD)

> - To give energy to; activate or invigorate:.
> - to rouse into activity.

Comment: I like that this is a real word that could fit. I might have to champion its usage and explain a lot, but it makes sense.

Comment: I do think this makes sense--however I've never used a CMS that I would consider 'energetic'. :)